# How can I use SOAP web service on REST App

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, soap

I'm developing Spring App with REST web service.

I have to use SOAP service from one of my clients.And I want to know how can I use client's SOAP service on my REST App.

I'm trying to create a SOAP client on my app and Use it for SOAP service. Are there any other ways to do that without creating a SOAP client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client provided you with a wsdl file, why not import it with wsimport (Oracle JDK) and use the imported classes?

Try this line:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/wsimport -Xnocompile -extension <somefile.wsdl>
```

Then add the java source files it creates into your environment.

Comment: Shloim, i havent any idea about that. ill try it.

Comment: Edited with a bit more information.